# Young's double slit experiment with two wavelengths of light

Tags: visible-light, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wavelength

I know that a double-slit experiment pattern for blue, and red light individually gives the intensity patterns easily found in textbooks. But I fail to understand the exact pattern produced by a double-slit experiment where both red AND blue light is used.

**My question:** When there is a question where it states that a light source is used where it emits both blue and red light in the following setup. And assume that red light is $1.5\lambda$ and blue light is $\lambda$, what is the intensity pattern observed on the screen?

[image]

I do not get a good visual representation of what will occur, but I do get approaching this by merging the intensity pattern for the blue light and red light individually. But cannot exactly describe the shape. I would appreciate the explanation.

Comment: We would get the superposition of a red double slit pattern with a blue double slit pattern. The minima of the red one are spaced wider apart than those of the blue one by a factor of 1.5. Nothing exciting. If we do the experiment with white light we get color fringes.

Comment: @FlatterMann This is correct. You should provide this as an answer rather than as a comment.

Comment: @FlatterMann, could you please help me explain this further more elaborately ?

Comment: Related [Why can bright and dark fringes form with white light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327870/why-can-bright-and-dark-fringes-form-with-white-light/327874#327874)

Comment: All the people who answered assumed that the source is assumed to be emitting the colours at the same time. However if the source is like a fluctuating source with the two colour states then the resulting pattern would also fluctuate with time shifting from red to blue to red etc.

Comment: @Amanpawar That's correct. The diffraction pattern of the double slit is no different from any other optical image of any other surface that way: it's illumination dependent. To maximize the contrast between the maxima and minima we usually chose to illuminate it with a coherent light source (ideally temporally and spatially coherent). If we do this with other objects, we will also often get to see interference phenomena that are suppressed by white light, like speckles.

Comment: @Amanpawar the illustration provided above with the question shows a single slit before the double slit. That single slit serves as a source of coherent light by acting as a spatial filter.

Comment: @BillAlsept the first pattern of your answer corresponds to multi-frequency source, other patterns are for monochromatic source. I'm not talking about spatial coherence.

Answer (score 0):

We would get the superposition of a red double slit pattern with a blue double slit pattern. The minima of the red one are spaced wider apart than those of the blue one by a factor of 1.5. If we do the experiment with white light we get color fringes.

Answer (score 0):

The separate patterns just overlay each other. Here is an example with Red, Green and Blue. Notice how the blue starts earlier, followed by the green and then red.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simlicity, let us forget about polarization and consider a scalar problem. Let us imagine that, at a certain point, two signals are interposed: $S_1=A_1\cos(\omega_1 t+\alpha_1)$ and $S_2=A_2\cos(\omega_2 t+\alpha_2)$ ($S_1$ and $S_2$ can be, for example, some component of the electrical field). The intensity will be proportional to $$(S_1+S_2)^2=$$ $$=A_1^2\cos^2(\omega_1 t+\alpha_1)+A_2^2\cos^2(\omega_2 t+\alpha_2)+2 A_1 A_2\cos(\omega_1 t+\alpha_1)\cos(\omega_2 t+\alpha_2)=$$ $$=A_1^2\cos^2(\omega_1 t+\alpha_1)+A_2^2\cos^2(\omega_2 t+\alpha_2)+$$ $$+A_1 A_2(cos((\omega_1+\omega_2) t+\alpha_1+\alpha_2)+cos((\omega_1-\omega_2) t+\alpha_1-\alpha_2).$$ When the intensity is averaged over time, the resulting intensity is the sum of intensities for the fields of frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ acting separately, as other answers state. Note however that there is also beating, which is observed experimentally when the frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are close. Please also note that the above calculation does not take into account the physiology of the human eye, which can see a combination of red and blue colors as some color that is different from both of these colors (see the picture in @Bill Alsept's answer).